# Vote count appears when hovered over

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, vote-count

The current vote count is shown only when the points are clicked on:

> [image]

to:

> [image]

It may be more convenient when the mouse cursor is hovered over the points and the vote count appears automatically until the mouse cursor is moved away.

Comment: I have no intention to do so. Gyazo does not grant me any money (edit: benefits) through advertising.

Comment: So why you don't use the built-in image upload offered by SE??

Comment: Because it says that the format is not supported.

Comment: Seeing vote counts is an "expensive" API call, and people will accidentally hover over all the time.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 because you tried to upload [this URL](https://gyazo.com/22850041a59f5797f99ae315ce55294f) which is a web page (HTML), and not an image. You needed to upload the [image file itself](https://i.gyazo.com/22850041a59f5797f99ae315ce55294f.png), or the actual image instead of uploading it to that external host in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

This will be declined for the same reason showing the breakdown from the outset has been continually declined.

To do that, the vote breakdown will have to be included in the query that retrieves the post list. (The information will need to be in the HTML in order for the mouseover to work.) The team has determined that this makes the query too expensive in terms of processing.

The current functionality allows for retrieving the vote breakdown for a single post with an AJAX call. They say that's a reasonable expense.

Comment: How do you do this vote count thing from the mobile browser? Edit: How do you do it from the mobile app that SE keeps pestering you to download?

Comment: @MaskedMan: You can't see the vote breakdown from the Android app. I expect the iOS is the same.

Comment: @ale vote breakdown can be seen when long pressing on the score on the iOS application.

Comment: Ah, yes. My mistake. Android app too.